# (plugin babel) Error: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json, npm-publish

I'm trying to create a npm package and
below is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "********",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "*****************",
  "keywords": [
    "exit",
    "intent"
  ],
  "main": "dist/*********.js",
  "module": "dist/********.es.js",
  "umd:main": "dist/********.umd.js",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "lint": "npm run prettier-eslint -- 'src/**/*.{js,json}'",
    "build": "rollup -c",
    "dev": "rollup -c -w",
    "prettier-eslint": "prettier-eslint --write --no-semi --single-quote --no-bracket-spacing",
    "changelog": "standard-version",
    "size": "npx gzip-size-cli ./dist/exit-detect.js ",
    "precommit": "lint-staged",
    "prepush": "npm test",
    "prepublish": "npm run build"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "src/**/*.{js,json}": [
      "npm run prettier-eslint"
    ]
  },
  "author": "Amaarshall Yaswankar",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.21"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.8",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.8",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "babel-plugin-external-helpers": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-lodash": "^3.3.4",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.1.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^16.0.3",
    "eslint-config-standard-jsx": "^10.0.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-node": "^0.3.6",
    "eslint-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.24.2",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^5.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.26.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^5.0.0",
    "husky": "^7.0.2",
    "lint-staged": "^11.2.0",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "prettier-eslint-cli": "^5.0.1",
    "rollup": "^2.58.0",
    "rollup-plugin-babel": "^4.4.0",
    "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^10.1.0",
    "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^5.2.0",
    "rollup-plugin-uglify": "^6.0.4",
    "rollup-watch": "^4.3.1",
    "standard-version": "^9.3.1",
    "uglify-es": "^3.3.9"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/********/*********#readme"
}
```

I'm using using `rollup` to build my package and below is the config file `rollup.config.js`

```
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve'
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs'
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel'
import {uglify} from 'rollup-plugin-uglify'
import {minify} from 'uglify-es'
import fs from 'fs'
const pkg = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./package.json'))

export default {
    name: '*********',
    input: 'src/********.js',
    output: [
        {format: 'es', file: pkg.module},
        {format: 'cjs', file: pkg.main},
        {format: 'umd', file: pkg['umd:main']}
    ],
    plugins: [
    resolve(),
    commonjs(),
    babel({
        babelrc: false,
        exclude: 'node_modules/**',
        presets: [
        [
            '@babel/preset-env',
            {
            modules: false,
            loose: true,
            targets: {browsers: ['last 2 versions', '> 1%']}
            }
        ],
        '@babel/preset-react',
        'babel-preset-stage-2'
        ],
        plugins: ['external-helpers']
    }),
    uglify({}, minify)
    ]
}
```

Now that all the babel packages are updated, I have tried updating the things as per the new versions. But still I'm facing the below error when I run `npm run build`.

```
rollup v2.58.0
bundles src/exit-detect.js → dist/exit-detect.es.js, dist/exit-detect.js, dist/exit-detect.umd.js...
[!] (plugin babel) Error: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions.
```

Not sure why this is happening, need your help guys

Thanks in advance

Comment: Guys, need your eyes here pls

Comment: Any help will be appreciated!